Kotlin Android Chat Images View
I have a question, how to make a photo layout, how is this implemented in all instant messengers? (Telegram)
If there are 5 photos, then in the first line there are two photos, in the second there are three
If there are 6 photos, then there are 3 in both lines
If there are 10, then the first one has 1 photo, and the rest have 3 photos.
Is this some kind of element? Maybe there is a ready-made library?
